# Pretty Zend Framework urls

Tags: zend-framework, url

I would like to have my urls like this:

- `/index`
- `/contact`
- `/articles`
- `/articles/selection`
- ...

Instead of:

- `/index/index`
- `/index/contact`
- `/articles/index`
- `/articles/selection`
- ...

Basically I have only one controller. Which solution is the best to perform this? (controllers and redirections, ZF routing, url rewriting, something else?)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation. The behaviour you want is configured as default in the default router:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

if the first param do not maps a module name, it will search for a controller and if this fails too, it is looking for an action in your IndexController. 
Did you tried calling your url's like you want to?
What happens if you navigate to `/index`? Should be the same like `/index/index`

Comment: That was what I suggested (see my question), but I'd like to avoid creating such simple controllers (1 action) if possible :/

Comment: So you have to configure your Router and set the type param like

    $article_route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/articles/:type', array('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'article', 'type' => 'index'));

And so on.

Answer (score -1):

use zend routing :

```
$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $route_index = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':action', array(
        'module'     => 'default',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'index'
    ));
    $router->addRoute('route_index', $route_index );

$route_articles = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('articles/:action', array(
        'module'     => 'default',
        'controller' => 'articles',
        'action'     => 'index'
    ));
    $router->addRoute('route_articles ', $route_articles );
```

Comment: If he do not overwrite the default router there should be no need to.

And i think your second url-descriptor should be '/articles/:action'.